# Как к Floating Action Button присоединить текст?

Tags: android

Что бы при появлении дополнительных кнопок, так же появлялось текстовое описание кнопок.
В прикрепленном скриншоте пример. Заранее всем спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему, в приведённом вами скрине используется вот эта сторонняя либа: [Clans/FloatingActionButton](https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton). А может и эта: [futuresimple/android-floating-action-button](https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button)

В любом случае, в стандартной гугловой реализации нет более одного FAB на экран и прочих надписей, ибо это не соответствует их видению FAB как таковых.

Так что берите вышеприведённые либы или пилите своё решение.